# Write a query that shows the difference between overall average Kilometers & each category avgerage Kilometers

Tags: sql, average, difference

I am trying to show the  difference between overall average Kilometers & each category avgerage Kilometers

```
SELECT AVG(Distance) AS avg_KM, Category
FROM project-348014.swvl.swvl
GROUP BY Category
ORDER BY Category ASC
```

that shows only the average of each category which they are three Category A, Category B and Category C so what to do ?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: This post does not explain how the desired output is a function of the input table.

Answer (score 0):

You could join both as you want to see the difference between them

```
SELECT
    Category,avg_km, (avg_Ges - avg_km) as Diff
FROM
    (SELECT AVG(Distance) AS avg_KM, Category
     FROM project-348014.swvl.swvl
     GROUP BY Category) t_cat 
  CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT AVG(Distance) AS avg_Ges
    FROM project-348014.swvl.swv) t_all
ORDER BY Category ASC
```

Comment: The code provided works in any sql language, as it is standard conform, your code shows that the table is called project-348014.swvl.swvl and you have a column Category and Distance. But in the deleted column you write something like Category.idnr  that is a different strucure altogther. so show a query that works for the avg per category or simply adept mine to what ever works.